# Como printear los datos dentro de un bucle ESPECIFICO de for en JAVA

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tengo un problema en un código sobre un examen modelo de parcial. Aqui una foto del enunciado.
Lo que yo quiero mostrar al escribir FIN en el nombre del libro, es que me diga el libro con mayor cantidad de paginas, lo cual SI HACE, pero de manera errónea. Al escribir FIN y pasar al segundo estante, al yo ingresar los datos de un libro y nuevamente poner FIN, debería decirme el libro con mayor cantidad de paginas de ese estante, no de todos los libros que ingresé por consola. Saben como podría llegar a arreglar eso?
(Foto de consola)
[image]

**(Foto de consola)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

package estanteria;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Libros {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int ESTANTES = 5;
    String nombreLibro, genero = "", libroConMasPags = "";
    int cantPaginas, cantMayorPaginas = 0, cantLibrosI = 0, cantLibrosN = 0, cantLibrosH = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < ESTANTES; i++) {

        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del libro ('fin' -> termina carga de estante °" + i + ")");
            nombreLibro = input.nextLine();
            if (!nombreLibro.equalsIgnoreCase("fin")) {
                System.out.println("Ingrese el genero del libro, Infantil, Novela o Historia: ");
                genero = input.nextLine();

                switch (genero.toUpperCase()) {
                case "I":
                    System.out.println("Cuantas paginas tiene?: ");
                    cantPaginas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

                    while (cantPaginas <= 0) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: tienen que ser > 0");
                        cantPaginas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    if (cantPaginas > cantMayorPaginas) {
                        cantMayorPaginas = cantPaginas;
                        libroConMasPags = nombreLibro;
                    }
                    cantLibrosI++;
                    break;
                case "N":
                    System.out.println("Cuantas paginas tiene?: ");
                    cantPaginas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    while (cantPaginas <= 0) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: tienen que ser > 0");
                        cantPaginas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    if (cantPaginas > cantMayorPaginas) {
                        cantMayorPaginas = cantPaginas;
                        libroConMasPags = nombreLibro;
                    }
                    cantLibrosN++;
                    break;
                case "H":
                    System.out.println("Cuantas paginas tiene?: ");
                    cantPaginas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    while (cantPaginas <= 0) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: tienen que ser > 0");
                        cantPaginas = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    if (cantPaginas > cantMayorPaginas) {
                        cantMayorPaginas = cantPaginas;
                        libroConMasPags = nombreLibro;
                    }
                    cantLibrosH++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (!nombreLibro.equalsIgnoreCase("fin"));
        if(nombreLibro.equalsIgnoreCase("fin")) {
            System.out.println("El libro con más paginas es: " + libroConMasPags + " con: " + cantMayorPaginas);
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Hay " + cantLibrosI + " libros Infantiles");
    System.out.println("Hay " + cantLibrosN + " Novelas");
    System.out.println("Hay " + cantLibrosH + " libros de Historia");
    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: La solución es simple. Setea las variables a su valor inicial dentro del `if` de `fin` luego de mostrar el mensaje. Así no se quedarán guardados en las variables los nombres del estante anterior.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono! y te hago otra consulta, viste que tambien te pide el promedio de libros por estante? como puedo hacer eso? no tengo idea como hacer que se guarden los datos de las variables anteriores sin sobreescribir los nuevos

Comment: Dentro del `if` de fin, solo debes resetear la variable `libroConMasPags` y  `cantMayorPaginas`. El promedio de libros por estante es fácil, porque sumas los libros de cada tipo y los divides entre 5. La cantidad de libros por género también ya que solo debes imprimir `cantLibrosH`, `cantLibrosN` y `cantLibrosI`